# Super method from Django documentation

Tags: python, django

Here is one piece from Django documentation:

```
  from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_something()
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
        do_something_else()
```

My hesitation is focus on the save method.
Why the author separates do_something from do_something_else?
Because of the existence of 'Call the "real" save() method',what's the meaning of do_something(),which seems to be "false" ?I even can do the manipulation:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
    do_something()
    do_something_else()
```

Am I right?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. The author is showing how to perform actions before and after saving. What do you mean that do_something is false? Why would you want to reorder it? What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 1):

`do_something()` and `do_something_else()` aren't real functions. They aren't defined. They are just hints for you to do something there, then, if you need, do something else, implementing even functions and calling them there, if you need.

Usually you need some field to automatically update/get a value when another field is saved. One way to do this is by overriding the model save method. And usually you do this before you call `super().save()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right.

**There is no deep meaning.**

The sentences just mean "You can write some methods which you want to do before *super().save* or after *super().save()*."

However, I slightly doubt that you know *super()* in detail, which is one of the syntax in python.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is just showing that you can fall functions (or write code) before or after calling a parent or sibling method with super.

But first of all, you must know [what super is](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)...

In your example, you e calling `save` with super, which triggers the django based methods and functions and do many other stuff that is within `ModelBase.save()`.

You are doing this to follow standart django save procedure.

**But**, you may want to make some checks or make some pre-save work, so you can call a method to do stuff that should be done before saving the model instance. Maybe you want to log the record time to a file and you just write a method and call it to log timestamp before you call `super().save()`

The same is also valid as post-save actions.